# How to count the progression of unique items, starting again at set dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
order_date  client_id
2019-11-04  0164653
2019-11-11  0164953
2019-01-02  0138584
2019-03-10  0144995
2019-06-06  0154688
2019-01-28  0141756
2019-12-01  0167299
2019-04-17  0148797
2019-02-20  0143585
2019-01-08  0139446
```

I would like to count the progression of unique *client_id* for every day of the year, initializing that count at the beginning of each month.
In the end I would like to put it in a new dataframe with many indexes as all the days of the year.
Something like that:

```
order_date  client_id
2019-01-01  8
2019-01-02  13
2019-01-03  18
2019-01-04  25
...
2019-01-31  97
2019-02-01  3
2019-02-02  9
2019-02-03  15
...
2019-12-31  95
```

I tried something like this:

```
dates = df.order_date.drop_duplicates()
x = []
y = []

for enum, date in enumerate(dates):
    if data <= pd.Timestamp("2019-01-31"):
        x.append(df[(df["order_date"] >= "2019-01-01")&(df["order_date"] <= date)].client_id.nunique())
        y.append(enum)
    if  (data > pd.Timestamp("2019-01-31")) & (date <= pd.Timestamp("2019-02-28")):
        x.append(df[(df["order_date"] >= "2019-01-01")&(df["order_date"] <= date)].client_id.nunique())
        y.append(enum)
    else:
        1
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO isn't a code-writing service

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it shows no effort

Comment: Sorry, I thought I would have had a step further before posting the question. Anyway I just added my attempt.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick:

```
df.groupby('order_date')['client_id'].nunique()
```

Comment: Thank you Giorgios. Though I would like to start the counts again at the beginning of each month. Let me know if it's not clear.

Answer (score 1):

First step is [`SeriesGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) and then groups by months with month periods by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) with [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('order_date')['client_id'].nunique().reset_index()
df1['client_id'] = df1.groupby(df1['order_date'].dt.to_period('m'))['client_id'].cumsum()
print (df1)
  order_date  client_id
0 2019-01-02          1
1 2019-01-08          2
2 2019-01-28          3
3 2019-02-20          1
4 2019-03-10          1
5 2019-04-17          1
6 2019-06-06          1
7 2019-11-04          1
8 2019-11-11          2
9 2019-12-01          1
```

Comment: Great! Very easier to what I was doing! Thanks